Why DirectByteBuffer keeps data on JVM heap instead of native memory in Android?
I wanted use ByteBuffer.allocateDirect to keep data on native memory but it looks like it keeps data on heap.
I used this code to check that DirectByteBuffer keeps data on heap.
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val tenMb = 10 * 1024 * 1024
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tenMb)

    init {
        if (byteBuffer.hasArray()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Byte buffer has heap array ${byteBuffer.array().size / 1024f / 1024f} MB")
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Byte buffer doesn't have heap array")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "BYTE_BUFFER_TEST"
    }
}

I got heap dump and saw that byte array with size 10 MB is kept on heap.
Image of heap dump
Also, I tried to allocate 300 MB to get OOM because a standard heap for Android app is 256 MB and I got it.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.myapplication, PID: 14976
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 314572819 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 253MB until OOM, target footprint 27560064, growth limit 268435456
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer$MemoryRef.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:71)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:265)
    at net.idrnd.test.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:10)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3839)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4126)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeNonLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:195)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:90)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

I have two questions:

Why DirectByteBuffer keeps data on heap? I was sure that we use for this goal HeapByteBuffer and use DirectByteBuffer to keep data on native memory.
How to keep data on native memory if DirectByteBuffer doesn't work properly and I don't want to use NDK?


What do you want to a hive by using "native memory"? The existence of several ByteBuffer implementations my be historical or may be only effective in certain environments or VM types. Don't forget that there are different implementations of the Java API and all you have to do is implement the API as it is defined. As long as the class has no definition that ensures that it doesn't use heap memory any implementation like in Android can place the memory anywhere it want.

@Robert
OK. Do you have a solution how to keep data outside of heap (and obviously filesystem) in Android?

If you want memory not controlled by VM use code outside of the VM thus NDK. But I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

@Robert
I need to allocate and use a lot of memory, 300-400 MB. When I tried to do it using heap I saw OOM after 256 MB. So, the solution is move data from heap to another place, e.g. native memory. I read several articales where was said - use DirectByteBuffer. I used. It doesn't work, so I came here and asked question which you can see with number 2 at the original post. You proposed to use NDK, it's OK, I have already implemented C++ code for my purposes but the question is stil there: is it possible to move data to native memory in Android java without using NDK?

I guess you already use largeHeap settings? That the Java VM does not provide a way to allocate non-managed RAM is what I an most likely most other Android developers would expect. Otherwise there would be a way to bypass the Memory Profiler of Android Studio and create massive memory leaks.

What happens if you create a large temporary file and map it to a byte buffer?

Instead of allocating the ByteBuffer in the init block, create it only when you need it and release it immediately after use. This approach minimizes memory usage. If you don't necessarily need 10 MB, consider allocating a smaller buffer size based on your actual data requirements. This reduces the upfront memory footprint. If you're dealing with large byte streams, explore alternative approaches like:

Streaming data in chunks instead of loading everything at once.
Using memory-mapped files for efficient access to large datasets.

